# loop multiple file with only 1st file being read

Tags: linux, bash

So I have a that works as it going to mulitple directories then within these directories takes multiple fields from files and store it in a .txt files.
There are two loop, the first one that loops through all the folder
the second one that loops through all the files.
The problem I encounter is in the second loops that it read only the first file in the folder and then it moves on to the next folder and ignore all other files in the folder.

```
archive=/imdata/archive
inventory_archive=/imdata/a/shares/b/inventory/c

ls $archive | while read p; do
   echo "Project: $p"
   mkdir -v $inventory_archive/$p
   dir=$inventory_archive/$p
   ls -1 $archive/$p/d001 | while read s; do
       echo "Searching Session: $s ..."
       find $archive/$p/d001/$s -type f -iname "*.txt" | while read f; do
           echo "FILE: $f"

           study=`/home/me/program/bin/script $f | grep -m1 "field1" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
           echo "SID: $study"
           if [ ! -d "$dir/$study" ]; then
                mkdir -v $dir/$study
           fi
           studydir=$dir/$study

           series=`/home/me/program/bin/script $f | grep -m1 "field2" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
           echo "SID_2: $series"
           if [ ! -a "$studydir/$series.txt" ]; then
                touch $studydir/$series.txt
           fi

           sop=`/home/me/program/bin/script $f | grep -m1 "field3" | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1`
           echo "SID_3: $sop"
           grep -qsF $sop $studydir/$series.txt || echo $sop >> $studydir/$series.txt

           exit 1;
       done;
   done;
done;
```

Comment: If the first (outer) loop is looking for directories how can you be sure if you do by "ls -1 $archive/$p/d001" this lists directories and files. If it outputs a file then the next "find $archive/$p/d001/$s" will only find that single file. Is that possible? PS: I have a hard time understanding your english (sorry if mine is not so good too :-) ).

Comment: [Don't parse the output from `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Why do you have `exit` in there?

Comment: the exit was orignally for testing purpose that it doesn't get out of controll, I think I forgot to remove it and it looks like that is the problem